Proof of Linear-Algebra (matrices).
Prove that
\begin{align}
  \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1\\
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}^n &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda^{n} & n\lambda ^{n-1}\\
0 & \lambda^{n}
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{align}
I have tried the following using induction (Base case is ok).
Here the inductive step.
I suppose that there exists some $k \ge 1$ for the problem. And I want to know if it also holds for $k+1$,
\begin{align}
    \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1\\
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}^{k+1} &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1\\
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}^k 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1\\
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix} \\
 &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda^{k} & k\lambda ^{k-1}\\
0 & \lambda^{k}
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1\\
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda^{k+1} & (k+1)\lambda^{k} \\
0 & \lambda ^{k+1}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Then is proven for $k+1$.
I'm not sure if the proof is ok. And I would like to know if there exists a proof without using induction.

The induction is correct.

Fun fact this has a beautiful generalization for analytic functions of matrices $$f\left(\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 1 \ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}f(\lambda) & f'(\lambda) \ 0 & f(\lambda)\end{pmatrix}$$

Another approach can be along the following lines, let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a &1\\0&a\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1 &0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0 &1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=aI+B$$
Then,
$$A^n=(aI+B)^n=a^nI+na^{n-1}B+\binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}B^2+\dotsb + B^n$$
Observe that $B^2=\begin{bmatrix}0 &0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. So, $B^k=O$ for all $k \geq 2$. Thus,
$$A^n=a^nI+na^{n-1}B=\begin{bmatrix}a^n &na^{n-1}\\0&a^n\end{bmatrix}$$
